# Codeigniter 3 session with redis - AUTH password

Tags: codeigniter, redis, codeigniter-3

I'm a beginner with redis. And i'm quite confused with the codeigniter 3 documentation.

I just installed a redis server and used the ci session library with redis in my app. It works quite well ... but nothing is mentioned concerning a password auth.

here is my config.php :

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'redis';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'tcp://localhost:6379';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

How am i supposed to ask for an authantification ? I suppose that everybody could access to my session table in the actual way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [session library documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html) has a bunch of links at its top, the so called "table of contents".

One of these links, aptly named "Redis Driver", points to ... the ["Redis Driver" section of the document](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#redis-driver), which contains barely a few short paragraphs, exactly so you don't get lost in between lots of text.

Only one of those paragraphs mentions the word "config", and it says the following:

> Just as with the ‘files’ and ‘database’ drivers, you must also configure the storage location for your sessions via the `$config['sess_save_path']` setting. The format here is a bit different and complicated at the same time. It is best explained by the *phpredis* extension’s README file, so we’ll simply link you to it:
>
> > https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#php-session-handler

Sure, the document doesn't contain the word "authentication", but this is hardly confusing ... you only have to click a link.

For clarity and to provide a specific example:
`"tcp://host:port?auth=password"`

Comment: I do not feel that this is a complete answer, you reference an external link and give some context, but no where do I see a clear and concise answer demonstrating how to include the password for authentication for the session_save_path; Everything I see has the socket type (tcp), host and port.  At first glance the only way I saw to auth is a separate command. Finally, I saw under the connect documentation that you could add 'auth:pwd' but there we no examples of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is working to me CI3 > config.php:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'redis';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'tcp://host*:port*?auth=password*';
```